# How to update content through a REST API call in Hippo CMS?

Tags: angularjs, http-post, hippocms

In Hippo CMS, I created a new content type, created new content of the said type as admin from the Hippo CMS UI and created a REST endpoint. I'm reading the data from an Angular web app through a **REST API** call (**GET**). To update or delete the content, I have to login as admin and change the content. Is there a way that I can update or delete the content in Hippo CMS using **DELETE** or **POST** REST API call?

I looked at this reference: https://www.onehippo.org/labs/rest-resources-and-hippo-cms.html. In `ProductResource.java`, there are `@GET` and `@Path("/")`. I understand that it takes **GET** requests. But I want to do something like `@POST` or `@DELETE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the Persistable annotation. You might use [this code](https://code.onehippo.org/cms-community/hippo-testsuite/blob/release/3.2/components/src/main/java/org/hippoecm/hst/demo/jaxrs/services/ProductContentResource.java) as a starting point. If you need more details, you can find it on [this documentation page](https://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/component-development/hstcomponent-persistable-annotation-and-workflow.html)